# How to deal with many users update over Document driven nosql database

Tags: nosql, couchbase

### Problem

Starting with nosql document database I figured out lots of new possibilities, however, I see some pitfalls, and I would like to know how can I deal with them.

Suppose I have **a product**, and this product can be **sold in many regions**. There is **one responsible for each region** (with access to CMS). Each **responsible modifies the products accordingly regional laws** and rules.

Since *Join* feature isn't supported as we know it on relational databases, *the document should be design in a way it contains all the needed information to build our selection statements and selection result* to **avoid round trips** to the database.

So my first though was to design a document that follows more or less this structure:

```
{
   type : "product",
   id : "product_id",
   title : "title",
   allowedAge : 12,
   regions : {
      'TX' : {
         title : "overriden title",
         allowedAge : 13
      },
      'FL' : {
         title : "still another title"
      }
   }
}
```

But I have the impression that this approach will generate conflicts while updating the document. Suppose we have a lot of users updating lots of document through a CMS. When same document is updated, the last update overwrites the updates done before, even the users are able to modify just fragments of this document (in this case the responsible should be able to modify just the regional data).

### How to deal with this situation?

One possible solution I think of would be partial document updates. **Positive:** reducing the data overwriting from different operations, **Negative:** lose the optimistic lock feature since locking if done over a document not a fragment of such.

Is there another approach for the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can use 3 solutions:

1. Leave current document structure and always check CAS value on update operations. If CAS doesn't match - call store function again. (But as you say if you have a lot of users it can be very slow).
2. Separate doc in several parts that could be updated independently, and then on app-side combine them together. This will result in increasing view calls (one for get main doc, another call to get i.e. regions, etc.). If you have many "parts" it will also reduce performance.
3. See [this](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-sample-patterns-joins.html) doc. It's about simulating joins in couchbase. There is also good [example](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2013/02/introduction-to-collated-views-with.html) written by @[Tug Grall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648508/tug-grall).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bounded to using Couchbase (not clear from your question if it's general or specific to it) - look also into MongoDB. It supports partial updates on documents and also other atomic operations (like increments and array operations), so it might suite your use case better (checkout possible update operations on mongo - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/ )